# Cannot use local docker image with docker desktop kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have this kubernetes yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: incremental-api-load-balancer
spec:
  selector:
    app: incremental-api
    tier: api
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: incremental-external-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: incremental-external-api
    tier: sidecar
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: incremental-api-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: incremental-api
      tier: api
      track: stable
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: incremental-api
        tier: api
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: incremental-flask-app
        image: incremental-flask
        imagePullPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: incremental-external-api-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: incremental-external-api
      tier: sidecar
      track: stable
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: incremental-external-api
        tier: sidecar
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: incremental-external-api
        image: incremental-external-api
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

When I do

```
docker images ls
```

I see

```
REPOSITORY                                  TAG                                        IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
incremental-flask                             latest                                     8bbc4c45efdf        2 minutes ago       1.21GB
incremental-external-api                        latest                                     532203259006        3 minutes ago       1.2GB
```

From looking at this answer - [Docker for Mac(Edge) - Kubernetes - reference local image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739405/docker-for-macedge-kubernetes-reference-local-image)

I should be pulling the local image.

However, I get this when I run

```
kubectl get pods

incremental-api-deployment-98b5d7c95-bmqbf         0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          1m
incremental-api-deployment-98b5d7c95-tktqv         0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          1m
incremental-api-deployment-98b5d7c95-xcwk2         0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          1m
incremental-external-api-service-deployment-b9dddff77-6z4p9   0/1       ErrImageNeverPull   0          1m
```

I am running a local cluster with Docker Desktop and I want to pull local images.

Why is this error happening?

Comment: What is your Kubernetes setup? Are you using minikube?

Comment: @Philibobby i believe he is using the build-in kubernetes solution that is part of docker distribution nowadays.

Comment: @praks5432 I am aslo facing the same problem. Do u hv any update about solution?

Answer (score 1):

> --image-pull-policy=Never

using "latest" tag will always force a pull, because the value for  imagePullPolicy:always , it will look for the remote repo to pull .

When you add the 'Never' option , local repo will be used

Answer (score 0):

Just use specific tag version instead of 'latest' (check configuration best practices [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)).

Comment: This answer is already included in the post he linked as not working for him.