# kubernetes: image can't be pulled

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

Before onboarding to the enterprise k8s / AWS EKS, I am using `docker-desktop` for local k8s testing on Mac with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

with the following deployment steps to `docker-desktop`:

```
docker build . -t cpchung/rema

kubectl create deployment rema --image=cpchung/rema --dry-run -o=yaml > deployment.yaml
echo --- >> deployment.yaml
kubectl create service clusterip rema --tcp=8080:8080 --dry-run -o=yaml >> deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

This generates the deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: rema
  name: rema
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rema
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: rema
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: cpchung/rema
        name: rema
        resources: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: rema
  name: rema
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-8080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: rema
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

and test the deployment with the following health check:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/rema 8080:8080
```

```
curl localhost:8080/actuator/health
```

But I am getting this error:

```
robinhood $ kubectl get all
NAME                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/rema-57df6cf5fc-px8pc   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          4m29s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    18h
service/rema         ClusterIP   10.100.78.60   <none>        8080/TCP   152m

NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/rema   0/1     1            0           4m29s

NAME                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/rema-57df6cf5fc   1         1         0       4m29s


robinhood $ kubectl logs rema-57df6cf5fc-px8pc
Error from server (BadRequest): container "rema" in pod "rema-57df6cf5fc-px8pc" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled
```

But I really have the image from dockers:

```
robinhood $ docker images
REPOSITORY                                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cpchung/rema                                    latest              14a4957873cd        2 hours ago         224MB
```

What could be wrong here?  I am using mac with docker-desktop.

Comment: Where is Kubernetes running and how? The image needs to be in a repository the cluster is configured to access.

Comment: could you also add your deployment.yaml file here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763242/3514300 should solve the issue for you

In your deployment add `imagePullPolicy: Never`

By default for images tagged with no tag are given the `latest` tag in docker. Kubernetes by default tries to pull the images for `latest` tag and it wasn't able to find the image in dockerhub. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images

Other way is to push your image to dockerhub too.

Comment: Adding `imagePullPolicy: Never` works, but followed by this error:

```
curl localhost:8080/actuator/health
{"timestamp":"2020-03-05T18:52:37.055+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/actuator/health"}
```

From the pod log, I see the service is running. so what could be wrong here?

Comment: double-check if you have enabled actuator correctly https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: even I use ```curl localhost:8080/api``` which is a endpoint implemented, it doesnt work. It works when I run it using ```docker run```

Comment: Add container port https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster in the deployment